# Using CROSS APPLY with GROUP BY and TOP 1 with duplicate data

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

I have a table that contains Status information about Product items over time. Each row has a Modified DATETIME. I want to get the latest Status row, using the MODIFIED field, for each ProductNumber in one query. However the crux is that the MODIFIED field may contain duplicates, so when I join back onto ProductStatus mulitple records are returned.

It will be used in a VIEW and so I must able to have WHERE clause with "ProductNumber = 123" at the end.

Sample Data:

```
ID | DateCreated             | ProductNumber | Modified
====================================================================
1  | 2008-09-29 00:00:00.000 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
2  | 2008-09-29 00:00:00.000 | 20070099      | 2014-11-10 20:22:59.467
3  | 2008-12-18 09:26:58.507 | 20070099      | 2014-12-10 20:22:59.467
4  | 2008-12-18 08:47:38.343 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
6  | 2007-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
5  | 2007-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 20070099      | 2014-02-10 20:22:59.467
11 | 2009-03-20 14:09:52.190 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
34 | 2009-03-20 14:18:49.383 | 20070099      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
```

---

SQL to create the data:

```
CREATE TABLE #ProductStatus ( ID INT, DateCreated DATETIME, ProductNumber INT, Modified DATETIME )

INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (1, '2008-09-29 00:00:00.000', 20070098, '2014-10-10 20:22:59.467')
INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (2, '2008-09-29 00:00:00.000', 20070099, '2014-11-10 20:22:59.467')
INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (3, '2008-12-18 09:26:58.507', 20070099, '2014-12-10 20:22:59.467')
INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (4, '2008-12-18 08:47:38.343', 20070098, '2014-10-10 20:22:59.467')
INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (6, '2007-12-07 00:00:00.000', 20070098, '2014-10-10 20:22:59.467')
INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (5, '2007-12-07 00:00:00.000', 20070099, '2014-02-10 20:22:59.467')
INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (11, '2009-03-20 14:09:52.190', 20070098, '2014-10-10 20:22:59.467')
INSERT INTO #ProductStatus VALUES (34, '2009-03-20 14:18:49.383', 20070099, '2014-10-10 20:22:59.467')
```

---

Getting the MAX Modified when Grouping by the ProductNumber,

```
SELECT ProductNumber, MAX(Modified) AS MaxModified
FROM #ProductStatus
GROUP BY ProductNumber
```

returns

```
ProductNumber | MaxModified
===========================
20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
20070099      | 2014-12-10 20:22:59.467
```

---

Based on this sample data the final recordset I am looking for is:

```
ID | DateCreated             | ProductNumber | Modified
====================================================================
1  | 2008-09-29 00:00:00.000 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
3  | 2008-12-18 09:26:58.507 | 20070099      | 2014-12-10 20:22:59.467
```

---

Using an INNER JOIN and a TOP 1 to get the ID from ProductStatus based on the MaxModified and ProductNumber,

```
SELECT MainProductStatus.* 
FROM #ProductStatus MainProductStatus
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 LatestProductStatus.ID
    FROM #ProductStatus LatestProductStatus
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SubLatestProductStatus.ProductNumber, MAX(SubLatestProductStatus.Modified) AS MaxModified
        FROM #ProductStatus SubLatestProductStatus
        GROUP BY ProductNumber
    ) MaxProductStatus
        ON MaxProductStatus.ProductNumber = LatestProductStatus.ProductNumber
        AND MaxProductStatus.MaxModified = LatestProductStatus.Modified
        ORDER BY LatestProductStatus.DateCreated DESC
) AS ProductStatusLatestSubQuery ON ProductStatusLatestSubQuery.ID = MainProductStatus.ID
```

results in this recordset, getting the TOP 1 from all of the MAX items:

```
ID | DateCreated             | ProductNumber | Modified
====================================================================
11 | 2009-03-20 14:09:52.190 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467
```

---

I then looked into CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY further but am getting mixed results, e.g.

```
SELECT MainProductStatus.* , ProductStatusLatestSubQuery.*
FROM #ProductStatus MainProductStatus
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID
    FROM #ProductStatus LatestProductStatus
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SubLatestProductStatus.ProductNumber, MAX(SubLatestProductStatus.Modified) AS MaxModified
        FROM #ProductStatus SubLatestProductStatus
        GROUP BY ProductNumber
    ) MaxProductStatus
        ON MaxProductStatus.ProductNumber = LatestProductStatus.ProductNumber
        AND MaxProductStatus.MaxModified = LatestProductStatus.Modified
    WHERE LatestProductStatus.ID = MainProductStatus.ID
    ORDER BY LatestProductStatus.DateCreated DESC
) AS ProductStatusLatestSubQuery
```

returns:

```
ID | DateCreated             | ProductNumber | Modified                | ID
===========================================================================
1  | 2008-09-29 00:00:00.000 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467 | 1
3  | 2008-12-18 09:26:58.507 | 20070099      | 2014-12-10 20:22:59.467 | 3
4  | 2008-12-18 08:47:38.343 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467 | 4
6  | 2007-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467 | 6
11 | 2009-03-20 14:09:52.190 | 20070098      | 2014-10-10 20:22:59.467 | 11
```

---

I'm really not sure why the CROSS APPLY isn't working as I expect. Maybe I need to get the DISTINCT ProductNumber records first to avoid extra-joining, but that doesn't help me get the end data.

---

I've checked out any similar items I could find on here before posting. This is my first question, feedback welcomed. TIA.

Comment: What makes ID 1 the correct row to be returned for 20070098, rather than 4, 6 or 11?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't state. When it has identical Modified and BusinessNumber I wanted to sub-order it. To be honest I'd want row number 11 which has the latest DateCreated, not row 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for MAX(Modified) field over ProductNumber, you can use ROW_NUMBER() function, and then get all rows where row number = 1.

> ```
> WITH selMax AS
> (
>     SELECT ID, ProductNumber, DateCreated, Modified,
>            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY Modified DESC, 
>                                                                   DateCreated DESC) RNum
>     FROM   #ProductStatus
> )
> SELECT ID, ProductNumber, DateCreated, Modified
> FROM   selMax
> WHERE  RNum = 1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | ProductNumber | DateCreated         | Modified           
> -: | ------------: | :------------------ | :------------------
> 11 |      20070098 | 20/03/2009 14:09:52 | 10/10/2014 20:22:59
>  3 |      20070099 | 18/12/2008 09:26:58 | 10/12/2014 20:22:59
> ```

> Filtering by ProductNumber:
>
> ```
> WITH selMax AS
> (
>     SELECT ID, ProductNumber, DateCreated, Modified,
>            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY Modified DESC, 
>                                                                   DateCreated DESC) RNum
>     FROM   #ProductStatus
>     WHERE  ProductNumber = 20070098
> )
> SELECT ID, ProductNumber, DateCreated, Modified
> FROM   selMax
> WHERE  RNum = 1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | ProductNumber | DateCreated         | Modified           
> -: | ------------: | :------------------ | :------------------
> 11 |      20070098 | 20/03/2009 14:09:52 | 10/10/2014 20:22:59
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a9ac3bd28393a44ac222b55b1dcf101c)*

Comment: To ensure consistency, I'd recommend adding an additional field to `ROWNUMBER()`'s `ORDER BY`. Based on sample output, currently it looks like `ORDER BY Modified DESC, Id ASC` might be right. Otherwise, there is a risk that (as the table is updated) it would return a different row in the future. as there are four possible rows with the same `Modified` value.

Comment: @RDFozz yes, you're right, but I was waiting for an answer to the comment on the question.

Comment: That makes very good sense. Still worth noting in case no response is forthcoming, or if someone else looks at this in the interim, but the final answer should be based on the actual requirements.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I needed to order the ROWNUMBER() by Modifed DESC, DateCreated DESC for my requirements but it works great out of the box. I am dealing with 400,585 rows in the real table and this runs the query in 0 seconds, so also a plus.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.